# Can we have a data Structure like map<string,pair<string,list>>?

Tags: c++, data-structures

I want to have a data structure of following type in c++.

```
map<string,pair<string,vector>>.
```

Any Suggestions?

Comment: `vector` needs a type: `vector<int>` for example. Apart from that, you can have that.

Comment: This has probably changed in the many years I haven't programmed in C++ but, I remember, you needed to put a space between the two greater-than signs. Otherwise, the compiler confused it with the shift-right operator.

Comment: vector is of type vector<myclass>.

Comment: @Eduardo - That *has* formally changed in C++11. Many compilers have implemented it already.

Comment: @Bo - Thank you! That's quite recent; I don't feel so old now :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
map<string,pair<string,vector>>
```

No. You cannot have a data structure like that.

The reason is : `vector` is a class template, which means it requires you to pass *type* as template argument to it. If you do that, then you can most certainly have a data structure like this:

```
map<string,pair<string,vector<T>>> data;
```

where `T` is some type.

Note that if you're using C++03 (or C++98), then you have to put extra space between each pair of `>` means  `>>>`  should look like `> > >`. However, in C++11, the extra space is not needed, means `>>>` should work just fine.

Comment: Shouldn't you put some spaces between `>>>` unless you are using newer C++?

Comment: That is needed in pre-C++11. In C++11, spaces not needed.

Comment: *newer* :-) Considering the probable level of the OP, his problem could be as simple as "my C++ is quite old and when I put two `>>` it breaks"

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can

```
std::vector<string>cache_entry
std::tr1::unordered_map<string,cache_entry>
```

Comment: Hunh? Is there a `typedef` missing here?